# Unable to install Cart with ubercart

Tags: 8, ubercart, installation

I'm trying to install Cart form ubercart after an uninstall:

I'm getting the following message what can I do?

> Unable to install Cart, image.style.uc_cart, uc_order.status.abandoned
>   already exist in active configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with drupal console, you can find it here: https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/index.html

The command to use is this:
drupal module:install --overwrite-config

Just install drupal console and use the command.

Comment: Is there a drush command as well?

Comment: Only for config import  config-import (cim)   Import config from a config directory.  For overwrite i did not found :(